# What is the use of the 'return' keyword

Tags: javascript, return, language-design

```
 const menu = {
    _courses : {
        _appatizers: [],
        _mains: [],
        _deserts: []
    },


get courses() {
    return {
        appatizers: this._courses._appatizers;
        mains:  this._courses._mains;
        deserts:  this._courses._deserts;
    };
}
```

I am more concerned by how this return is used as an object;
please explain as much you can to clarify the concept, thank you.
forget about the code.

Comment: `return {}` means you are returning an object from function.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/return

Answer (score 0):

The **`return`** statement does exactly that: returns a value from a function.
The return value can be any type, not only an object.

```
function returnNumber(){
    return 1;
}

function returnString(){
 return 'My string';
}

function returnObject(){
    return {a: 'one', b: 'two'}
}
```

All of the previous are valid, but you can do the same with arrays, or even return functions from functions...

If you don't explicitly return something from a function, it will implicitly return undefined.

Answer (score 0):

With `return` you can do exactly what it says: return something. This can be anything: a number, a string, an variable, an array, an object (...).

So in your case, the function returns an object.

A more simple example:

---

```js
function someNumber() {
  return 42;
}

var number = someNumber(); // somerNumber() will return 42, so number will have the value 42
console.log(number);
```

For a way more detailed reference, you may want to take a look at [this](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_return.asp).